# Get value and clear input field in one statement

Tags: javascript, jquery

I was using the `val()` function from jQuery to retrieve the value of an input field and then to clear it.  While it's not a huge deal, it's annoying to have to do this in two statements; is it possible to "pop" the value from an input field using jQuery or JavaScript?

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ZqYvd/)

**HTML:**

```
<input id="myInput" name="myInput" type="text" contenteditable="true" style="width:100%" />
<input type="button" id="Btn" value="Clear"/>
<div id="last" name="last"></div>
```

**JavaScript / jQuery:**

```
$().ready(function() { 
    $("#Btn").on("click", function(){
        $("#last").html($("#myInput").val());
        $("#myInput").val("");
    });
});
```

Just to be clear, I'm trying to replace the functionality of these two lines with one line:

```
$("#myInput").val();
$("#myInput").val("");
```

Comment: No, that's not possible, and there's no reason it should be

Comment: you can not get and set at the same time

Comment: My sugestion is to write a function yourself for this.

Comment: @Dinizworld  - Not sure why one would ever need that, but like this -> **http://jsfiddle.net/ZqYvd/1/**

Comment: If you want one line of code, then put it on one line. That's what semicolons are for.